# How to run a node file in the browser once a day

Tags: node.js, browser, cron, cron-task

I am trying to run a script (crawler.js) that scrapes some information from a soundcloud url and creates a json file. I am able to create the json file, but I have to manually run `node crawler.js` in my terminal to update the results.

Note: This will live on a website

My Goal: Once a day, run the crawler.js script and update the episode.json file.

I can't put crawler.js in a script tag because I am using Nightmare as a npm package to do the scraping.

I've heard and looked into cron jobs and xvfb, but I'm not sure if those options are too heavy for my purposes.

Comment: use normal cron `0 0 * * * node crawler.js`, nothing is lighter than that.. or the node-cron npm package to do it programmatically with pm2 startup to start the script on boot.. xvfb or running in a browser is not the solution

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks! For the cron option, and because I've never done cron jobs before, is this another script that I would Include in my sources files? Since the website I am building is a simple static website that I will host on Netlify, I'm wondering how the job will get executed.